# HTML input jQuery UI datepicker vs iOS native date input

Tags: ios, html, jquery-ui, mobile, webkit

I have a page which has some input type="text" with a jQuery UI datepicker attached, which enters the date in the format "14 Feb 2012" into the field. Great. Now I need to adapt the interface for mobile/small screen. I am having the issue that when an iPhone user taps in the text input, the jQuery datepicker appears, and iOS also shows it's native text input keypad.

I tried using Modernizr to detect for html5 inputtype=date availability and disabling the jQuery datepicker if it's available and switching the input type to "date" so devices which understand this can use their native input. However, this enters the date on the format "2012-02-14" which the back end system does not understand. A lot of work has been done depending on the date arriving in the format "14 Feb 2012".

So if anyone can help, I'm looking for a way to get ONLY the jQuery UI datepicker to appear on all systems, or for a solution which means native date/text inputs can be forced to enter the format "14 Feb 2012".

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the datepicker format can't be overridden due to it being tied to the user's system settings.

What you could do though in fact is have your script do the dynamic switch from type="text" to type="date" based on available technology (e.g. Modernizr.inputtypes.date).

From there you could embed a hidden field and transition the name of the current date field to that hidden field and then parse the date format from the native datepicker into your desired format and set that value of the hidden field.

```
<input type="date" name="userSetDate"/>
```

to this:

```
<input type="date"/>
<input type="hidden" name="userSetDate" value="mm/dd/yyyy"/>
```

The difficulty would then be parsing the user defined format into your desired format because of the format variations:

10-06-13 --> is that October 6th 2013 or June 10th 2013 ?

---

Now you could do something that incorproates the top solution with something like styling a label to look like a button, apply an accurate [for] attribute and have the datepicker field be a type="hidden" and apply the datepicker to that.

```
<label for="fooDate">test</label>
<input type="hidden" name="fooDate" id="fooDate">

<script>
$('#fooDate').datepicker();
</script>
```

Hope you're (were, noticed the date this was posted) able to figure out!